# How to create formula in infopath form

Tags: infopath, infopath-rules

Good day!

Just want to ask on how to create a formula in infopath form? i mean i dont want to connect it to SP list since its taking too long to load (tried it)

So here's my scenario, I have a 2 values in dropdown list:

1. Urgent Request
2. Normal Request

I have a textbox beside the dropdown list.

When i select the Urgent Request - it should say "Urgent request needs approval"

When i select the Normal Request- it should say "Normal request is 1 day SLA"
Is this possible?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If I'm getting you right you want the user to pick up an option from a drop down field and based on their answer you want to alert them a message, right?

So you have a drop down field (DropDownField) and a text field (TextField)

I won't use a formula for this ,just set 2 action rules on the drop down field, you need the "set value rule" and add a condition

1. when DropDownField equals Urgent Request set TextField "Urgent request needs approval"
2. when DropDownField equals Normal Request set TextField "Normal request is 1 day SLA"

Answer (score 0):

Just add two calculated value control above your drop downfield with the different messages and then create a formatting rule for them that goes:

```
If Dropdown is not equal to "Urgent Request" then hide this control.

If Dropdown is not equal to "Normal Request" then hide this control.
```

The calculated values will not create any extra space when hidden in your form, and they will not be added as columns to your SharePoint list.

[image]